# " ".join(list) not inserting spaces when calculating field

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3, python-2.7

I have a Python script where I'm trying to take the values from three fields (street address data - direction, street name, street type) and combine them into one field, e.g. S, Main, St should be S Main St.

I've tried three different ways, in code below, but no matter what I try the result comes out as 'SMainSt', no spaces. If the direction field, is empty, it results in ' MainSt', even when I use strip().  If the street name is two or more words, the space there is preserved, e.g. 'SHollow WoodsLn'. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

```
street = ('!FEDIRP!', '!FENAME!', '!FETYPE!')
val = " ".join(street)
val = "{0} {1} {2}".format("!FEDIRP!", "!FENAME!", "!FETYPE!")
val = "!FEDIRP!" + " " + "!FENAME!" + " " + "!FETYPE!"

arcpy.CalculateField_management(f, fld, val, 'PYTHON_9.3')
```

Comment: Is it script? Exclamation marks are good in field calculator....

Comment: Yes, in a script.

Comment: I guess missing quota around expression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use the Calculate Field tool (instead of an Update Cursor), what you're assigning to `val` needs to be an *unevaluated* python expression. That is, it needs to be identical to the string you would type into the Calculate Field tool if you were using the GUI version.

What you're currently assigning to `val` is `"!FEDIRP! !FENAME! !FETYPE!"`.

Any of the following should work:

```
val = ''' " ".join([!FEDIRP!, !FENAME!, !FETYPE!]).strip() '''
val = ''' "{0} {1} {2}".format(!FEDIRP!, !FENAME!, !FETYPE!).strip() '''
val = ''' (!FEDIRP! + " " + !FENAME! + " " + !FETYPE!).strip() '''
```

Alternatively, you could use an Update Cursor:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(f, [fld, 'FEDIRP', 'FENAME', 'FETYPE']) as c:
    for r in c:
        r[0] = " ".join(r[1:]).strip()
        c.updateRow(r)
```

Comment: This almost works, It still leaves a space at the front of the string - ' Main St' instead of 'Main St' - if there's no value for FEDIRP. I use .strip() to eliminate this space, but it's not working.

Comment: Is the .strip() inside the triple-quotes?

Comment: No, like this:  val = ''' "{0} {1} {2}".format(!FEDIRP!, !FENAME!, !FETYPE!) '''.strip()

Comment: I've updated my answer with the `.strip()` in the appropriate places. You're making the same error as your original one: your entire expression for the calculation must be unevaluated for it to work.

Comment: That did it, much appreciated!